# sed stdin faster than reading from file?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to determine if sed is faster reading from stdin (with shell redirection < ) or by specifying the file from which sed should read.  I didn't find a definitive answer on Google.

Which is faster?

```
sed -e "expression" < file
```

or

```
sed -e "expression"   file
```

Comment: why dont you try it out?

Answer (score 1):

It should be basically indistinguishable.  In both cases, the file has to be opened and a file handle created.  In both cases, sed then reads from the file handle.  In the first case, the shell opens a file handle and then passes it via process inheritance to sed as a child.  In the second case, sed opens the handle directly.  As I said, that should be pretty much indistinguishable.

Comment: @AlanShutko: There's no pipe involved here. If you think `sed` would be reading from a pipe in this case, what do you think is writing to that pipe?